# componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n" does not work on NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
NSString *URLString = [[url absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *temp = [URLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
return YES;}
```

that does not split the string, though preview shows \r\n are still in the string.
Any suggestions?

input URL sample- myapp://bla\r\nbla

here is string after replacing % esc and splitting by '\r\n':

[image]

here is url before replacing % esc:
[image]

I suspect replacing percent escapes has got to do something with it.

Comment: Can you post your input string?

Comment: Can you give us the url, before you replace percent escapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Eduardo but closer to your code, the following:

```
NSString *URLString = @"myapp://bla\r\nbla";
NSArray *temp = [URLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
NSLog(@"%@", temp);
```

Outputs:

```
2014-03-20 12:05:17.247 Untitled 3[437:507] (
    "myapp://bla",
    bla
)
```

Is it possible your incoming string contains the literal four-character sequence \r\n, which would be written as `@"\\r\\n"` rather than the sequence of two control codes, \r\n?

Comment: hurray, it split using '\\r\\n' got to give you right answer, sorry malex, Tommy got it a little bit earlier

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
NSArray *temp = [URLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\r\\n"];
```

Your initial URLString can't contain CR LF. It simply contain two-symbol literals '\r' and '\n'

Answer (score 0):

Does it shows "\r\n" in preview? This works:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [@"abc\r\ndef" componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"]);
```

If your code does not work, are you sure your string doesn't contains "\\r\\n" instead of "\r\n"?

**EDIT:** SO "unescaped" my double-slashes

Comment: Does that final sentence say what you intended it to say?

Comment: do not think it does, but somebody bumped him up already, what for?